# Xcode : How to validate the app in organizer : iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

This is the first time i am uploading my app in iTunes.

First I made a developer provisioning profile, set the code signing (in build settings) and tested the app in my device.

Then I only made distribution Provisioning profile to upload the app in iTunes and downloaded the provisioning file. I double clicked and I got the the id in code signing under build settings. [NOTE: I did perform any changes in Certificates and Identifiers. Bundle identifier of the app also matches the app id in distribution - provisioning]

I added my app in iTunes connect and shows a yellow dot saying "Prepare for upload"

I build and archived.

When click on distribute and select fist option  "Submit to iOS appstore", i get a dialogue box "Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode."

Which step did I miss?

Comment: Go to iTunes Connect and click in "Ready to upload binary". Once its status wil be changed you will be able to upload it to app store from XCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only step you're missing is going to your iTunes Connect page, manage application, click on the app you want to upload and then click "Ready to upload binary"

Something like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to iTunesConnect, and click on your app and click to "`Ready to Upload binary`", and then go back to XCode and do once again archive and upload it.